# Why is $ y \le 0$ one of the solutions of the equation $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = -y $?

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

Why is $ y \le 0$ one of the solutions of the equation $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = -y $? Or is the answer (at the end of my book) wrong. 
I know that the other solution is x=0, but $y \le 0$ can't be verified.

After some calculations we arrive at $ y = -y$... but if we substitute with $-3$, for example, we get: $ -3 = -(-3) \rightarrow -3=3 $.

Comment: the square root is always nonnegative, so $y \leq 0$

Comment: It's not "one of the solutions", it's a condition on the solution.  A solution has to tell you both $x$ and $y$.  Here $x$ must be $0$, and $y$ can be anything $\le 0$.  For example, $x=0$, $y=-3$ is a solution because $\sqrt{0^2 + (-3)^2} = 3 = -(-3)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution of this equation is an ordered pair $(x,y)$. Now observe that squaring both sides gives $x=0$. So you are left with the equation $\sqrt{y^2}=-y$. Now, do you know that one of the definitions of absolute value is $|y|=\sqrt{y^2}$? Combine this with the piecewise function definition of $|y|$, and you will get $y\leq 0$.